# get the result from function and post it to select tag

Tags: php

I do have a file of **function.php** and code is.

```
function getPositionRecord(){
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "Select * FROM position");
  return mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,$result));
}
```

and i have a **home.php** file which has a

```
<?php 
    $position = getPositionRecord(); 
    foreach ($position as $key => $value) { 
?>
<select>
    <option value="<?=$value['PositionId']?>"><?=$value['PositionName']?> 
    </option>
</select>
```

what i like to happen is after getting the values from the functions.php it will pass through the home.php on select tag. I include the functions.php in the home.php file.

Comment: what do you see `print_r($position)` with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already got the answer. it tried this one on my functions.php

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_query($conn, "Select * FROM position"), MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $result;
}
```

and my select tag was populated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you need to change a bit of code here.

function.php

```
function getPositionRecord(){
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "Select * FROM position");
return $result;
}
```

home.php

```
<select>
<?php $position = getPositionRecord();

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($position))
{
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['PositionId']; ?>"><?php echo $row['PositionName']; ?></option>
    <?php
}
?>
</select>
```

You can loop through data while returning $result object from there.

Comment: so far its getting better than before unfortunately i got an error when i tried your code,

Comment: my error says Notice:  Undefined index: PositionName in D:\projects\test\home.php on line 415

Comment: just print $row array and check what you get

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are only fetching one row of results in `getPositionRecord`, so your `foreach` loop is operating on one row of data, and `$value` will not be an array as you expect. The way your code is written at present you need to fetch all the results in `getPositionRecord`:

```
function getPositionRecord() {
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "Select * FROM position");
    $rows = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
}
```